# Is the acceleration of an object a linear function?

Tags: acceleration

Let's assume that I have a dataset with the variable *acceleration* which is a time needed for a car to speed up to 60 mph. Now I would like to transform this to time needed for a car to speed up to 100 kph.

But I assume that one cannot just simply count it like this `x=y*62,14/60` (x is the acceleration time for 100 kph, y is the original time for 60 kph and 62,14 mph is 100 kph) because the function is not linear but logarithmic right?

Comment: Acceleration can be a non linear function of a variable too. See inverse square forces like gravitation, for example.

Comment: But is the conclusion that one cannot just simply count it like this? That speeding for instance from 90 kph to 95 khp won't take the same time as speeding from 95 kph to 100 khp? The latter will take more energy therefore more time, won't it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't extrapolate like this and the function may be neither linear nor logarithmic.

The car is subject to frictional forces from air-resistance, rolling-resistance, gear-train resistance, resistive forces inside the engine and other resistive forces. Each of these depends not only on speed but also on other factors like shape, selected gear, engine RPM, engine temperature, driver skill etc.

Two cars might accellerate to 60 in the same time but be different in major respects.

For example some cars that can reach 60 mph might not be capable of reaching 100 kph (62.14 mph) at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a real car, the answer generally is that it takes longer to accelerate at higher speeds... but that's because of the gears, not the forces at work. If you're just talking about acceleration, at least at speeds low enough to ignore relativistic effects, then any acceleration that produces a certain change of speed will take the same energy regardless of initial speed. A constant acceleration of 1m/s^2 will change your speed by 1m/s each second, whether that's from 0 to 1m/s or from 1000 to 1001m/s.

The only exponential (not logarithmic) relation to acceleration that we normally bother with is the *position* of an object. Summary: constant ("flat") acceleration will cause a linearly changing velocity which produces an exponential change in position.